# Como formatar o template literal do javascript?

Tags: suporte, formatação

O template literal do javascript é marcado com o carácter **`**, como colocar ele dentro de um código inline em comentários e respostas?

Tentativas:

````
```
`\``
`\\``
`\\\``
````

Lembrando que tudo que abre, fecha

Edit:

Como sugerido, basta aumentar a quantidade de acentos que limitam o início e fim do código, mas se o código começar com o acento grave? Dai não funciona:

````
```bla = ${bla}```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Trechos de código que possuem o acento grave**

Basta utilizar dois acentos graves como limites do seu código *inline*:

```
``console.log(`Sua string`)``
```

Desta forma, os acentos graves internos serão escapados e não quebrarão a formatação do código, ficando `` console.log(`Sua string`) ``.

Se, por algum motivo, precisar utilizar dois acentos graves seguidos dentro do código, basta utilizar três para limitar o código:

````
```console.log(``Uma `string` qualquer``)```
````

Que resultará em ``` console.log(``Uma `string` qualquer``) ```

**Trechos de código que começam com o acento grave**

Quando o trecho começará com o acento grave, ele não poderá ser o primeiro caractere, senão quebra a sintaxe do editor. Neste caso, bastaria colocar um espaço em branco como primeiro caractere:

```
`` `bla = ${bla}` ``
```

Que, inline, ficaria: `` `bla = ${bla}` ``, onde o espaço é praticamente imperceptível.

**Nos comentários...**

Já, nos comentários, utilizar a barra invertida para escapar o caractere funciona:

```
`\`bla = ${bla}\``
```

Não precisando do espaço em branco, nem de mais acentos graves.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para poder colocar o problema

Comment: `` `bla = ${bla}` `` então ... meio estranho, o editor formata de forma diferente no comentário e na reposta/pergunta (além claro dos códigos em bloco, com 4 espeços)?

Comment: `\`aceita = ${true}\``, só me fica a dúvida de por que tanta diferença, mas já to feliz com a resposta

Answer (score -4):

Assim?

```
`Meu nome é ${nome}`
```

É só botar 4 espaços antes.

Comment: código inline `tipo esse`

Comment: Bem, acho que poderia ser algo `\`assim\``

Comment: Nos comentários deu certo, no corpo da pergunta, não.